# approaches to WCF service version control

Tags: wcf, versioning

We are implementing numerous services in our company and running into versioning issues with data contracts. One of the problems we have is that our data contract are also used as the model of the actual application behind the service. I was wondering what approach others have taken in this kind of situation or just service versioning in general. I am aware of the microsoft best practices guide but wanted to see if anybody has any other ideas on how to version.

Answer (score 2):

The first rule of Services, Business Object != Message Object.   Basicly, never expose your business objects as data contracts.  Or as I like to say, you can't fax a cat.  You can send a facsimile of a cat, but you can't send a cat over the wire.  Here's a great picture to remind you: http://www.humorhound.com/2009/04/demotivational-poster-youre-doing-it-wrong/

In more modern terms, it is really the MVVM pattern.  The view of the model that the domain layer uses is not built for a client, so you have to create a separate model and view for the other layers.  Yes it seems like a lot more work, but in the end it is a much easier and better way to build service oriented applications.  Versioning is just one of the ways that it makes life easier.  The other important thing is that you tend to build models that are geared around how it is going to be used, and you wind up with more explict code (less crazy branching).

Answer (score 0):

The way that we have implemented this is to build a facade layer on top of the business layer.

The facade layer talks to the rest of the world using the objects defined in the data contracts.

The facade layer maps the objects to internal objects before sending the data into the business layer.

This isolates the internal functionality of your system from the objects used in the data contracts.